# How to handle errors and interrupt while streaming with AvPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, streaming, avplayer

I am using `AVPlayer` for stream **video** from a URL like this :

```
-(void)initVideo
 {
    AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@VideoFileURl",Video_BASE_URL]]];
    avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    AVPlayerLayer * avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer];
    avPlayerLayer.frame = self.imageUserImage.frame;
    avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResize;
    [self.imageUserImage.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];
    [self.avPlayer.currentItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
    [avPlayer play];
 }



- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
if (object == self.avPlayer && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {


    if (self.avPlayer.currentItem.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
        NSLog(@"AVPlayer Failed");

    } else if (self.avPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
        NSLog(@"AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay");
    } else if (self.avPlayer.currentItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown) {
        NSLog(@"AVPlayer Unknown");

    }
   }
}
```

Every thing works fine & my video load as well but in some condition my video is paused forever ( hang up in a frame and doesn't continue ) !

**Problem**

I only receive the `AVPlayerStatusFailed` notification in start of a stream if  there is a problem but I need to get a notification while streaming like interrupt or loose a connection while streaming.
Please help me how can I handle the network error during streaming ( interrupt in a connection & change a network status -> Like `reachability`

**UPDATE**

i find a solution , i should use `AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification`
but i don't know why i give this **Continuous**